# Overlay circular video with transparency with maskedmerge

Tags: ffmpeg, snapchat

I have a square video from Snap Spectacles (1088x1088) that I want to overlay on itself zoomed in and blurred.

Example input frame:

[image: original snap spectacles video frame]

Generated zoomed in and blurred background:

[image: generated zoomed in and blurred background]

Desired output:

[image: desired output]

I think I can do this with [ffmpeg's maskedmerge](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#maskedmerge), but I'm having trouble finding examples.

There's [an example of maskedmerge that merges two videos of the same size and dynamically removes a green screen](http://oioiiooixiii.blogspot.co.uk/2016/09/ffmpeg-extract-foreground-moving.html), and another that [merges videos with transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415651/ffmpeg-merging-videos-with-transparency#17453585).

Here's the closest I've been able to get:

`ffmpeg -i background.jpg -vf "movie=input.jpg[inner];[in][inner] overlay=#{offset}:0 [out]" -c:a copy output.jpg`

[image]

tl;dr: given the first two frames, how could I generate the third frame (as video)?

Comment: You'll need to create a circular mask for the main video, and alphamerge that mask with the video.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got it!

[image]

Like @Mulvya recommended, I needed a circular mask:

[image: ffmpeg circular mask]

Given that mask `snapmask.png`, a blurred square background video `background.mov`, and the original video `65B6354F61B4AF02_HD.MOV`, they can be merged like this:

```
ffmpeg -i background.mov -loop 1 -i snapmask.png -filter_complex " \
[1:v]alphaextract, scale=1080:1080 [mask];\
movie=65B6354F61B4AF02_HD.MOV, scale=1080:1080 [original];\
[original][mask] alphamerge [masked];\
[0:v][masked] overlay=420:0;"\
-c:a copy output.mov
```

You can do one better, though, which is generating the blurred background video on the fly in the same command. Now the only inputs are the original spectacles round video and the circular mask:

```
ffmpeg -i 65B6354F61B4AF02_HD.MOV -loop 1 -i snapmask.png -filter_complex "\
[0:v]split[a][b];\
[1:v]alphaextract, scale=1080:1080[mask];\
[a]scale=1080:1080 [ascaled];\
[ascaled][mask]alphamerge[masked];\
[b]crop=946.56:532:70.72:278, boxblur=10:5,scale=1920:1080[background];\
[background][masked]overlay=420:0"\
-c:a copy 65B6354F61B4AF02_HD_sq.MOV
```

That `crop=946.56:532:70.72:278` bit is what I found worked best to crop out a rectangular portion of the circular video to zoom into.

It took me a while to wrap my head around the ffmpeg filter system for how to do this, but it's not as scary as I'd initially thought. The basic syntax is `[input]command args[output]`, and commands can be chained without explicitly naming their outputs (like in `[1:v]alphaextract, scale=1080:1080[mask]`).

Comment: I am trying your solution and get "No such filter: ''".

Comment: @MaorBen sounds like it might be a syntax error in the way you're running the command. Try deleting all the \ at the end of each line and making the command one gigantic single line.